# Servlet Send Double Quotes to Webpage as Ajax

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I have a servlet that I want to send javascript via ajax call:

```
private String returnImage(String img, String imgFailOver) {
String str="<img src='http://Foo.com/images/"+img+".jpg' onError='this.onerror = null; this.src=\""+imgFailOver+".jpg\";' height='500' width='500'/><br/>";
return str;
}
```

**Basically trying to have servlet send this:**

```
<img src="image.png" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/images/noimage.gif';" />
```

**From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images?lq=1) SO doc.**

My question/ problem is why do the escaped double quotes in servlet not register (get ignored) on the webpage?
[image]

*PS- I'm tagging Java and Javascript b/c I'm not sure what side to fix this on?*

Comment: what does the actual response look like that comes from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `&quot;` instead of `\"`. The HTML parser in the browser is unable to read `\"`, this is a Java double quote escape.